# ReactNative - Tapping row in ListView gives error: Cannot read property `_pressRow` of null

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I am building a small ReactNative + Redux app using a `ListView`. I was following the example code from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) and came up with the following setup. My current implementation is very close to the sample code, but for some reason, I am getting an error when I want to "click" a list item.

Here are the relevant parts from my code:

#### JobsRootComponent.js

```
class JobsRootComponent extends Component {

  ...

  _pressRow(row) {
      console.log('JobsRootComponent - _pressRow ', row)
  }

  ...

  _renderRow(rowData, section, row) {
      const title = rowData.title
      const subtitle = 'by ' + rowData.by
      return (
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow(row)}>
           <View style={styles.cellContainer}>
             <Text style={styles.cellTitle}>{title}</Text>
             <Text style={styles.cellSubtitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
           </View>
         </TouchableHighlight>          
      )
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      )
  }

  ...

}
```

This code looks fine to me, but for some reason, when clicking a list item, javacript crashes and displays the following two errors in the chrome dev console:

1. Cannot read property `_pressRow` of `null`
2. Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property `_pressRow` of `null`

According to my understanding, this means that the object whose `_pressRow` property was targeted with the click is actually `null`. But shouldn't that object be my `JobsRootComponent`? How come it can be `null` at this point?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After searching for a while, I came across [this tutorial describing how to implement a simple ToDo-app](https://devdactic.com/react-native-firebase-todo/) which helped me solve the issue myself.

The problem was due to the way I assigned `_renderRow` to the `renderRow`-property of the `ListView`: Instead of simply doing `renderRow={this._renderRow}`, I needed to use javascript's `bind()` function:`renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)`.

For reference, here is what my `render()` method now looks like:

```
render() {
  return (
      <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
        renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
      />
    )
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't bind like this in the render method. It would be best to bind your methods in a method called by your constructor or use arrow functions: bindMyMethods() { 
this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this); }